# Ссылка из двух слов. Как перенести второе слово на другую строку?

Tags: ссылки, перенос-слов

Есть ссылка на "Privacy Policy". Policy выступает за блок. Можно ли переносить слова в ссылке на новую строку? Если нет то есть ли какие-то костыли?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1)Уменьшите шрифт  || Поставьте более тонкий || Сместите флажок левее || Перенесите текст на новую строку, если это блок </br>

Comment: Это вообще про `HTML` или про что, где ссылка то? Или может `CSS` какой? Проставьте релевантные теги к вопросу.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Так как это у нас `label` Material-ского чекбокса. То решилось назначению `label` свойства `display: contents`